# How to sync jquery flexsliders?

Tags: javascript, jquery, flexslider

Why is my code not working? I have followed all the instructions! First init the slider that will control the other. Add asNavFor: and sync:. HTML has no errors. Both sliders work just fine on their own but for some reason they will not sync... Frustrating!

```
$(".flexslider2").flexslider({
    slideshow: false, 
    animation: "slide",
    direction: "vertical",
    reverse: true,
    controlNav: false,
    animationLoop: false,
    directionNav: false,
    asNavFor: ".flexslider"
});
$(".flexslider").flexslider({
    slideshow: false,
    animation: "slide",
    direction: "vertical",
    directionNav: false,
    animationLoop: false,
    controlNav: false,
    sync: ".flexslider2"
});
```

HTML

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery.flexslider.js"></script>
<div class="container">
    <div class="flexslider2">
        <ul class="slides">
            <li><div class="slide slide4"></div></li>
            <li><div class="slide slide5"></div></li>
            <li><div class="slide slide6"></div></li>
        </ul>
    </div>
    <div class="flexslider">
        <ul class="slides">
            <li><div class="slide slide1"></div></li>
            <li><div class="slide slide2"></div></li>
            <li><div class="slide slide3"></div></li>
        </ul>
    </div>  
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

not sure what you have in mind exactly, but you should make sure the slider that works as the navigation shows more than one slide, so the user can click on them to change the slides of the second slide.

So etiher add an "itemWidth":

```
itemWidth: 100
```

or do not disable the directionNav.

Demo:

http://jsfiddle.net/JC46C/